# Split array with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

Assuming I have a list

```
var listOfInt = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14}
```

How can I use LINQ to obtain a list of lists as follows:

```
{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {7, 8}, {12, 13, 14}}
```

So, i have to take the consecutive values and group them into lists.

Comment: what is the crieteria on basis of which you split

Comment: @Co.Aden: As they wrote, they want contiguous ranges of numbers in individual subsequences.

Comment: @Јοеу then it must be {1,2,3,4},{7,8},{12,13,14}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create extension method (I omitted source check here) which will iterate source and create groups of consecutive items. If next item in source is not consecutive, then current group is yielded:

```
public static IEnumerable<List<int>> ToConsecutiveGroups(
    this IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield break;
        }
        else
        {                    
            int current = iterator.Current;
            List<int> group = new List<int> { current };

            while (iterator.MoveNext())
            {
                int next = iterator.Current;
                if (next < current || current + 1 < next)
                {
                    yield return group;
                    group = new List<int>();                            
                }

                current = next;
                group.Add(current);
            }

            if (group.Any())
                yield return group;
        }                
    }
}
```

Usage is simple:

```
var listOfInt = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14 };
var groups = listOfInt.ToConsecutiveGroups();
```

Result:

```
[
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
  [ 7, 8 ],
  [ 12, 13, 14 ]
]
```

---

UPDATE: Here is generic version of this extension method, which accepts predicate for verifying if two values should be considered consecutive:

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> ToConsecutiveGroups<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T,T, bool> isConsequtive)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield break;
        }
        else
        {                    
            T current = iterator.Current;
            List<T> group = new List<T> { current };

            while (iterator.MoveNext())
            {
                T next = iterator.Current;
                if (!isConsequtive(current, next))
                {
                    yield return group;
                    group = new List<T>();                            
                }

                current = next;
                group.Add(current);
            }

            if (group.Any())
                yield return group;
        }                
    }
}
```

Usage is simple:

```
var result = listOfInt.ToConsecutiveGroups((x,y) => (x == y) || (x == y - 1));
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for both sorted and unsorted lists:

```
var listOfInt = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 12, 13 };
int index = 0;
var result = listOfInt.Zip(listOfInt
                            .Concat(listOfInt.Reverse<int>().Take(1))
                            .Skip(1), 
                            (v1, v2) => 
                            new 
                            { 
                                V = v1, 
                                G = (v2 - v1) != 1 ? index++ : index
                            })
                        .GroupBy(x => x.G, x => x.V, (k, l) => l.ToList())
                        .ToList();
```

External `index` is building an index of consecutive groups that have value difference of `1`. Then you can simply `GroupBy` with respect to this index.

To clarify solution, here is how this collection looks without grouping (`GroupBy` commented):

[image]

Comment: It is omitting the last value of the input.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your input is *in order*, the following will work:

```
var grouped = input.Select((n, i) => new { n, d = n - i }).GroupBy(p => p.d, p => p.n);
```

It won't work if your input is e.g. `{ 1, 2, 3, 999, 5, 6, 7 }`.

You'd get `{ { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 }, { 999 } }`.

Comment: +1 for most concise/elegant given the constraint. However, easily remove the constraint with an `OrderBy` like so: `input.OrderBy(n=>n).Select((n,i) => new { n, d=n-i }).GroupBy(p => p.d, p => p.n);`

Comment: @msorens The `OrderBy` ruins the consecutive test, though. `1 2 3 8 1 2 3` should be `{ 1 2 3 } { 8 } { 1 2 3 }` but gets jumbled if you sort it.

Comment: Good point; I was assuming the values were unique, but no reason they would have to be in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var results =
    listOfInt
        .Skip(1)
        .Aggregate(
            new List<List<int>>(new [] { listOfInt.Take(1).ToList() }),
            (a, x) =>
            {
                if (a.Last().Last() + 1 == x)
                {
                    a.Last().Add(x);
                }
                else
                {
                    a.Add(new List<int>(new [] { x }));
                }
                return a;
            });
```

I get this result:

[image: results]